# How to prevent NodeJS heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, stack-overflow, heap-memory

I have the following error:

> `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Which is a result of the following code, which works as one would expect when I attempt 4 chars, but not 8:

```
const _secret = 'NICHOLAS';

const charset = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

const maxLen = 8;

const maxGuesses = 999999999;

let answer;

let guess = '';

let curGuesses = 0;

function doCheck(passwordToReverseEngineer){
        function getRand(){
                return charset.split('')[Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length)];
        };

        while (guess !== _secret){
                if (guess.length <= maxLen){
                        ++curGuesses;
                        guess += getRand();
                        console.log(`Now trying this combo: ${guess}`);
                }
                else if (curGuesses === maxGuesses) {
                        throw new Error(`Limit of ${maxGuesses} has been reached.`);
                }
                else {
                        guess = '';
                }

                setTimeout(()=>{
                        doCheck(passwordToReverseEngineer);
                });
        }

        answer = guess;

        console.log(`The secret has been cracked and it is ${guess} after ${curGuesses} attempts.`);

        return true;
}
```

How could I avoid this so that the server can handle `n` number of guesses before reaching an out of memory exception such as the one above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should follow the async recursion model instead of using a while loop

```
function getRand() {/*code here*/}

function doCheck(password,attempts, key, callBack ){
  /* try to decrypt */
  const decrypted = decryptOperations(key);
  if(decrypted === secret){
    return callBack(null, decrypted);
  }

  if(attempts === MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
    return callBack(new Error('max num of trials'));
  }

  setTimeout(() => doCheck(passwords, attempts+1,...., callBack))

}
```

this is following the callback model, you can achieve similar result returning an internally created promise and passing it through the chain instead of the callback.

`
    function doCheck(password,attempts, key, resolve, reject ){
      if(!resolve){
         return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
           setTimeout(password, attempts, key, resolve, reject) 
         })
      }

```
  const decrypted = decryptOperations(key);
  if(decrypted === secret){
    return resolve(decrypted);
  }

  if(attempts === MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
    return reject(new Error('max num of trials'));
  }

  setTimeout(() => doCheck(passwords, attempts+1,...., resolve, reject))

}
```

`

please pay no attention to the decryption logic implementation, since it was not my intent to provide functional code, rather show you how to accomplish the async logic. You can also use generators for this but i can't provide the syntax out of my head right now since i am not that familiar with it. i hope this helps

Comment: I will be testing this now, Ill let you know how it goes thanks so far for the help

Comment: glad this helped out of curiosity which path did you implement?

Comment: I ended up using both first the callback and then promise, since I always use callbacks like its the 80's or something haha. I then added lower upper and caps to the brute force approaches to each charset in order to fit the real word a bit. Next I plan to introduce child process forks and spawn multiple child fork processes and see which finishes first and where I can optimize from there :)

Comment: nice. if you have time try using generators or async/await and let me know how it goes